# How to make bootstrap accordion headings(links or buttons) lay horizontally on the same line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The bootstrap [accordion demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) on the getbootstrap website has the panel headings laid on separate lines. 
I want to achieve the same collapsible effects, but I want the headings to be on the same line and the content opens below. The first example on that link does exactly that, but the problem is that when an accordion opens and you try open another one, the old one still stays. I want it to disappear immediately.

The accordion example does that but it's links or headings are on separate line, I want them to be on the same line, like a navbar.

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What Exactly you want ?

Comment: I want buttons or links to be laid on the same line, clicking each of them opens up a div containing content relative to that button, and clicking on another button closes any opened div and opens its div. The two examples in the getbootrap website in the collapse section each has a part of the solution.

Comment: Are you wanting to have all the heading on one row and the content panels for each open up underneath them? If so, you'd have to change the HTML markup and styling to match the layout you're after. As long as the data and aria attributes are still there, the component functionality will still work.

Comment: Please any practical example to illustrate what you are saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you're looking for it's called tabs, and Bootstrap has some classes for that like `tab-content` and `tab-pane`.

**UPDATE**:

I've also added `previous` and `next` button, as per the OP's request.

See the working snippet below:

```js
$('#prev').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  if ($('.active').not('li:last')) {
    $('#next').text('Next');
  }
});


$('#next').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  if ($('.active').is('li:last')) {
    $(this).text('Submit');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab_1" aria-controls="tab_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_2" aria-controls="tab_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_3" aria-controls="tab_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_4" aria-controls="tab_4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_1">Content 1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_2">Content 2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_3">Content 3</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_4">Content 4</div>
  </div>

  <a id='prev' href='#' class="btn btn-primary">Prev</a>
  <a id='next' href='#' class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>
</div>
```

You can read more about Bootstrap tabs **[here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage)**.

Comment: Exactly that. But I'm surprised I couldn't remember for once that bootstrap has that tab feature. Still new in the system :-D Thanks very much.

Comment: @ultraslim, you're welcome. Happy to help. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. Thank you.

Comment: @lonut If I want to customize the tabs to use a next and previous button for cycling through the divs instead of the tabs, how will I implement such a feature in jQuery?

Comment: @ultraslim, see my updated answer. I've added two buttons and a jQuery code that's finding the next and previous elements and handling the clicks. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @lonut, Thanks very much. Somebody should please up vote this answer.

Comment: I wanted to change the text of the next button as soon as the navigates to the end of the links by clicking, not direct access fro the tab. So I modified your code like this:  `var length = $('.nav-tabs > li > a').length; //number of items in tabs
 var counter = 1;
 $('#next').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  counter+=1;
  var text = (counter==length) ? 'Submit' : 'Next';
  $(this).html(text);
 });`  It works, but please check if it can be improved or some best practices.

Comment: @ultraslim, Hi. Sorry for the late reply, had a lot of work these days. You can do it much more simply. I've also made it to change the text back on click on prev button. See the updated answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Each tab content is a form that the user will have to fill. So at the hit of the submit button I will expect that none of the fields in all the tabs is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of the HTML structure you'll need, just to give you an idea. As mentioned in my comment above, you'll have to adjust your CSS.

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```